# Is there a way to get the last selected row in interactive grid oracle apex 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using oracle apex 5.1 and I created a page with interactive grid.
What I want to do is to get the last checked row data from interactive grid.
All I found on the internet is generating all the checked rows but not the last selected one which I will use to display more information about that last selected row.
Is it possible, can someone help me? thanks.